# Redis storage - AuthenticationFailure on PING

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, stackexchange.redis, telerik-reporting

Switched File Storage to Redis. Id="StackExchange.Redis.StrongName" version="1.2.6

I have attached the code below.

```
var configurationOptions = new ConfigurationOptions
            {
                EndPoints = { "" },
                Ssl = true,
                SslProtocols = SslProtocols.Tls12 | SslProtocols.Tls13,
                Password = "",
                AbortOnConnectFail = false, // Added
            };

            configurationOptions.CertificateSelection += delegate (object sender, string host,
                X509CertificateCollection certificates, X509Certificate? certificate, string[] issuers)
            {
                var cert = new X509Certificate2(PATH_TO_CERT_FILE);
                return cert;
            };

            configurationOptions.CertificateValidation += delegate (object sender, X509Certificate? certificate, X509Chain? chain,
                SslPolicyErrors errors)
            {
                //validation logic
                return true;
            };
            var redis = await ConnectionMultiplexer.ConnectAsync(configurationOptions);
```

I can't able to connect with Redis, showing the error like below

```
AuthenticationFailure on PING
```

**Notes:**
Using the correct End Point and password. Also tried with valid X509Certificate.

**Can someone please help to resolve the problem.**

In Telerik I needs to Use Redis Storage. But in redis couldn't able to make the connection.